# jQuery applying CSS style with an effect like FadeIn() one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In a jQuery script I'm applying a CSS style to a html table row to highlight it on a row link click:

```
$(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "silver");
```

How can this changing  color effect be appied softly with an effect like fading in a hidden object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color can be animated using jQuery. The easiest way to accomplish this is to use the [Color Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color). Also, if you are already using jQuery UI, it also [supports this functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

Comment: All project's links on the Color Plugin page are broken. Does anybody know new ones?

Comment: @qwertymk Thanks, is there any page with tips how to apply the effect?

Comment: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/ number 8 , Or you can use Archonix's syntax

Comment: @rem - Sorry about the broken links. You may also want to look at the jQuery UI plug-in. It has many other (excellent) features, and remains heavily supported and used. If you require any of the other features of the library, it may be better to use the same one for both of your needs.

Comment: @JasCav Thank you! Maybe I'll try the UI, not sure. In fact at present I don't need additional features the UI can suggest and I'd like not to have additional load on the page. What is the minimum weight of the UI plugin file the page should download to implement the color animation?

Comment: @rem - If you head here (http://jqueryui.com/download) you can actually customize what is available with the jQueryUI. So, as a result, you can strip out a lot of what you don't need, thus reducing the overall footprint. I don't know the minimum weight off the top of my head, but you can find out there.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: You need to use **JQuery UI** as well.

```
$(this).closest('tr').animate({ backgroundColor: "silver" }, 1000);
```

Replace 1000 with how long you want it to take to change to silver.

Comment: JasCav was a little earlier with a jQuery UI suggestion. Anyway, thanks for the code example +1